# I Want to Display the Fetched API in this code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render my json data into a table, but the code doesn't seem to render my data. This is what I've tried so far.

How can I render my data into the table?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Reactable from "reactable";

var Table = Reactable.Table;
var Thead = Reactable.Thead;
var Th = Reactable.Th;

export class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pgNo: 0
    };
    var self = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
      self.setState({
        pgNo: self.state.pgNo + 1
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(Users),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin"
    }).then(response => response.json());
  }

  renderTable() {
    return (
      <Table
        className="table"
        style={style}
        filterable={["id", "display_name", "username", "email", "address"]}
        noDataText="No matching records found"
        itemsPerPage={5}
        currentPage={this.state.pgNo}
        sortable={true}
        data={this.state.Users}
      >
        <Thead>
          <Th column="id">ID</Th>
          <Th column="display_name">Name</Th>
          <Th column="username">Username</Th>
          <Th column="email">Location</Th>
          <Th column="address">Occupation</Th>
        </Thead>
      </Table>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderTable()}</div>;
  }
}

const style = {
  marginLeft: "18%",
  marginRight: "5%"
};
```

Comment: store response in `state:user` using `setState`

Comment: You are not doing anything with the response to your `fetch` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: How can i do that. can you please rewrite the code, i am very new to react.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the data you can do a regular `fetch` with no other options, parse the `json` response, and set the result as your `users` in your state.

**Example**

```
export class Users extends Component {
  state = {
    pgNo: 0,
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          users: res
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table
        className="table"
        style={{
          marginLeft: "18%",
          marginRight: "5%"
        }}
        filterable={["id", "display_name", "username", "email", "address"]}
        noDataText="No matching records found"
        itemsPerPage={5}
        currentPage={this.state.pgNo}
        sortable={true}
        data={this.state.users}
      >
        <Thead>
          <Th column="id">ID</Th>
          <Th column="display_name">Name</Th>
          <Th column="username">Username</Th>
          <Th column="email">Location</Th>
          <Th column="address">Occupation</Th>
        </Thead>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made API call in fetch but not stored response data in `state`.

Define you state in a constructor as an empty error to avoid break

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }})
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(res=>this.setState({Users:res.users}))
```

Comment: It still isn't displaying anything after adding
 .then(res=>this.setState({Users:res.users}))

Comment: have you defined `Users` state in constructor with empty array assigned

Comment: Problem is you used method **POST**  instead of **GET**. Try debugging you are not getting a response what you supposed